# Is UDP always unreliable?

Tags: sockets, udp

I'm about to re-architect a real-time system that has been prototyped on a single node and specify how it should be scaled up to multiple nodes (probably never more than 20 of them in any one LAN). Some of the functionality will multiply on a per-node basis, and some of it will remain centralised on a one-per-system basis. There is going to be a need for communication between each node and that central unit (possibly a master node), but not between individual nodes.

Due to the real-time demands of the system, UDP is something that should be considered for that communication. But... it is almost always described as unreliable. Is this always the case? Does it not depend on the scale of the network, the data load on the network and the way the protocol is used?

For example, suppose I have a central unit which regularly polls through each node by addressing a UDP message to it, and each node immediately responds with its data via UDP. There is no other communication on the (isolated) network. Suppose there is also some mechanism to ensure there are never any collisions (e.g. all nodes have a maximum transmission length for their responses to a poll message, and the latencies are nailed down to known levels). Is there any (hidden) reason in a simple and structured network like this that you would ever fail to transmit/receive every last UDP packet and have near 100% reliability?

**EDIT:** the detail of this question suffers from confusion around what "unreliable" means, and whether it is intended to apply only to UDP, or to the system in which UDP is employed. I have chosen to leave this confusion in the question, because looking back over a lot of material on UDP, I can see  that this confusion might be very common, and that answers which highlight that confusion and overcome it might be valuable.

Comment: No. *Sometimes* UDP is reliable, but you cannot tell when.

Comment: It totally depends on context. In the context of the GigE Vision standard, UDP provides highly reliable image transmission at high data rates, and (usually) with the ability to detect dropped images. UDP itself may not tell you when it has failed, but the data transmitted via UDP can provide that information in cases like this.

Comment: [Might be of interest](https://www.openmymind.net/How-Unreliable-Is-UDP/).

Comment: For the record: we engineered a very reliable solution using UDP and have been using it for several years without any obvious issues. The answers below still strike me as generally more pessimistic than they need to be, and unwilling to consider the special case context: an isolated network. I might have got similar answers if I had asked "Can I build a skyscraper from spaghetti if it's not intended for humans?" Sure: don't cook the spaghetti; restrict access to creatures bee-sized or smaller. Context is everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreliability with regard to UDP is different from unreliability in general. Also, UDP and alternatives to it (e.g. TCP) are always only ever components or single layers in a wider system. This can lead to some confusion about what "unreliable" means.

UDP is a transport layer network protocol. The transport layer is responsible for getting data from one point on the network to another specific point on the network. In that context, UDP is described as an "unreliable" protocol because it makes no guarantees about whether the data sent will actually arrive. In contrast, TCP is a "reliable" transport layer protocol because if data goes missing or is corrupted the first time it is sent, the protocol itself has mechanisms to resend the data and ensure it arrives... eventually.

But UDP is not some sloppy "maybe, maybe not - let me think about it and screw you around" protocol. It does what it is specified to do, and is reliable (general sense) at doing it... as well as reliable (general sense) in failing in predictable ways. If you take these failure modes into account elsewhere, UDP can be a component of an overall very reliable system.

For example, by restricting network topology and using UDP to transport higher level protocols, the GigE Vision standard specifies a highly reliable system with high data transfer rates and real-time response whose transport level communications is dominated by UDP traffic.

Historically, the major source of unreliable packet transport was packet collisions due to two sources attempting to transmit simultaneously on a single channel. In modern networks, each node is typically connected on a full duplex link to a network switch, making collisions impossible on that link, and consequently making modern networks much more reliable (in all senses) than was the case when UDP was first designed.

Comment: I have not found other answers as clear or constructive as I'd like them to be. This answer reflects my current understanding. If it is incorrect, I'd really appreciate comments or edits to highlight where there is misunderstanding.

Comment: Historically and currently, the major source of packet loss is routers dropping packets under load, or indeed any time they feel like it, which they are perfectly entitled to do. The media-access layer collisions you refer to have precisely nothing to do with it. Your view of UDP is far too optimistic. Provided you build in your own ACK-based or NACK-based protocol, sequencing, retransmission, flow control, etc., UDP can be made to be reliable. Without that, it simply isn't, period, because there are zero design features in it to provide reliability. You have to provide them all yourself.

Comment: I simply disagree, and do so based on what I believe to be fact. Historically, routers practically did not exist in comparison to the numbers of terminal nodes, because the world was full of LANs. Packet collisions on those single duplex LANs were real and were the major source of unreliable transport. But that was engineered out as the world moved to the internet and full duplex connections over UTP. So I agree with you regarding the current state of affairs in general internet/WAN context. But I still strongly disagree in a simple, well-engineered (ie not overloaded) LAN context.

Answer (score 8):

The key is, UDP does not make any guarantees. There are many reasons why datagrams might go undelivered:

- Sender host buffers fill up
- Cosmic rays flip bits somewhere along the way, causing a checksum mismatch and the datagram to be discarded
- Electromagnetic interference corrupts the signal momentarily
- A network cable gets unplugged for a moment
- A hub or switch loses power for a moment
- A switch's buffers fill up
- Receiving host buffers fill up

If any of these things (or many others) occurs, a datagram may go undelivered. UDP will make no attempt to detect this or to re-deliver it.

Comment: I didn't set out to answer my own question, but your answer and the other one offered tend to emphasise "UDP is unreliable" far too strongly for my likes... which I feel is as widespread as it is unhelpful. If you feel my answer is inaccurate, I'd appreciate your comments on it so as to improve it.

Comment: @omatai Your likes don't really have anything to do with it. These are the facts whether you like them or not. There cannot possibly be anything 'unhelpful' about the truth, except possibly to those who don't wish to hear it.

Comment: Wait a minute. Facts may be facts, but context can render facts irrelevant. That's my point. To say that the above failure modes are definitive reasons to reject UDP in favour of TCP is under-informed. Most answers here are fine in an Internet/WAN context, but the question is about a real-time application on an isolated LAN in which there is (implicit) total control over the network design and traffic. My tests of a UDP-based design with no reliance on packet sequencing, ACK/NACK or similar have yet to drop a single packet in days. Is UDP always - ALWAYS!! - unreliable? Maybe not.

Comment: @omatai This answer does not state that these are 'definitive reasons to reject UDP over TCP'. That's your interpretation. You're welcome to do that, but not to put words into other people's mouths. 'UDP always' is just silly. And you're not supposed to provide two answers here to any question, let alone your own.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Every layer is potentially unreliable, starting with the electrical signalling across your Ethernet cable. (Ever jostled one of those plugs? You can see it in Wireshark logs.) Collisions are virtually impossible to avoid. And in case of congestion, your protocol stack may decide to drop UDP packets.

But all that's rather beside the point. UDP is unreliable, but that doesn't mean it *can't be relied on*. Plenty of mission-critical applications run over UDP. You just need to understand the unreliability and account for it.

Comment: I didn't set out to answer my own question, but your answer and the other one offered tend to emphasise "UDP is unreliable" far too strongly for my likes... which I feel is as widespread as it is unhelpful. If you feel my answer is inaccurate, I'd appreciate your comments on it so as to improve it.

Comment: I think the reason there is a widespread emphasis on UDP's unreliability is so that programmers will take that into account. It is possible to detect and resend dropped packets in the application layer or simply tolerate unreliability if the traffic isn't mission-critical.

Comment: @Sneffel - you say "collisions are virtually impossible to avoid". I am yet to see one, admittedly on a very simple network. I note that Wikipedia's page on Ethernet states "In full duplex, switch and station can communicate with each other simultaneously, and therefore modern Ethernets are completely collision-free." That is my experience. Do you have a different one that applies to an isolated LAN context on a modern network?

Answer (score 4):

Unreliable does not mean it will definitely fail. It only means that it does not care about transport problems and thus will not make any guarantees that transmission will be successful. Let's compare some aspects of UDP against TCP.

- UDP is packet based, TCP stream based. This has not much to do with reliability.
- Packets may arrive in a different order than they were sent. UDP does not care and will deliver the packets in this order to the application. In TCP data have a sequence number so the receivers operating system will detect reordering and forward the data to the application in the correct order. This usually does not matter when you have a direct connection between client and server, but might happen in wide networks like the internet.
- Packets may get lost due to router or switch congestion or overload of the senders or receiving system or others. This might also happen in local networks with heavy traffic or if the receiver system is unable to cope with the amount of data, even for a short time. With UDP the data will be lost. TCP instead will detect lost packets and retransmit them and even slow down the traffic to adapt to what speed network and endpoints can handle and thus loose less packets in the future.
- Packets might get duplicated. Again TCP will detect this due to the sequence number but UDP will not and thus transmit the duplicate packet to the application.
- Packets might get corrupted. Both TCP and UDP have the same kind of checksum to detect small errors, but will not detect larger errors.

Applications using UDP usually does not need the reliability of TCP or don't need all of this. For instance with real time audio and video packet loss is acceptable but duplicates and reordering is not. Thus the RTP protocol contains its own sequence number (timestamp) to detect this case. Also, RTP is often accompanied by the RTCP protocol to send statistics about packet loss back to the peer and thus make adaption of connection speed possible.

Comment: it's also true that if you decide to have a buffer of 100 bytes in your application, and you get a payload of 130 bytes, you just get nothing, usually not even the first 100 bytes of the 130 bytes, if the payload is larger than the associated buffer it gets discarded automatically and to the application it looks like it never got there . This is under POSIX AFAIK .

Comment: Yes, not having enough buffer space is one of the ways to loose packets.

Comment: @user2485710 That is not correct. You can get the first 100 bytes of a UDP datagram if you use the `MSG_TRUNC` option to `recv()/e=recvfrom()/recvmsg()`, and indeed truncation is the default behaviour in Java.

Comment: The default behavior of recv is to discard packets which do not fit into the provided buffer. I'm not sure about Java but I don't see any obvious way to specify something like MSG_TRUNC. In any way, even with MSG_TRUNC at least the part of the packet which does not fit into the buffer is lost, i.e. you don't get it with the next recv.

Comment: @SteffenUlrich Truncation, and therefore `MSG_TRUNC`, is the *default* in Java, as I already said. It's clearly stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want reliable UDP, try looking at ENet library.

http://enet.bespin.org/

Answer (score -2):

No networking technology currently available can be made 100% reliable... but let's be practical rather than pedantic, because potential unreliability and actual unreliability are a lot like shark attacks - they tend to occur far more in people's minds than in reality.

Some material on UDP makes it sound almost like the people who designed UDP did it just to annoy people - that unreliability was deliberately engineered in. This is not the case, and it is unhelpful to think of it in these terms. It is far better to focus on what UDP does and does not do in comparison to alternatives (e.g. see this [comparison between TCP and UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP)... which nonetheless lists "unreliability" as a key feature of UDP).

In reality, when there is data to be transmitted, that can be transmitted, it is transmitted; when there is data that can be received, it is received. Likewise, if you transmit packets 1, 2 then 3 directly to an endpoint, they will almost certainly be received as packets 1, 2 and 3 in order (assuming no failures in lower network layers, and that incoming data is buffered in a FIFO as is customary, but not mandatory). You can get a lot of reliability out of this, depending on how you use it.

However, if you transmit packets via multiple routes, all bets are off - "unreliability" of packet order can occur. And if you flood the available buffers, unreliability via dropping packets will occur. And if you allow nodes to transmit at any time (asynchronous), then you will get unreliability through packet collisions. But in the "simple and structured" (and also small and synchronous) LAN described, you may be able to either avoid this, or detect its occurrence (e.g. by sending an incrementing counter value in each packet), which will let you compensate in an application-specific way.

In cases where the power goes off (perhaps momentarily), or cosmic rays strike, or people trip on loose cables causing an unacceptable level of "unreliability"... then don't blame UDP - blame the engineer(s) whose design left the system susceptible to these things.

All things considered, in the LAN described, you might reasonably expect to be able to engineer a system based on UDP so as to never lose more than one packet in every few million, or billion, or even astronomically better than this - but it will depend on specifics, and only you can know if your application can tolerate the quantity and quality of unreliable comms that results in your case.

Comment: The practical advice here would be to design your software with the assumption that packets can be dropped, or that they might be delivered out of order -- that is, make sure those events are handled with some modicum of grace.  That way, if they rarely or never actually happen, then great, but if (when!) they do happen, your system won't fall over.  Note that even if you can't envision how a packet could get dropped today, there's nothing to say that some minor tweak to the system (e.g. new kernel version, new Ethernet chip, full moon) won't cause it to start dropping packets someday.

Comment: Note also that a dropped UDP packet is not necessarily an indication of an engineering failure at any level.  There is a significant amount of validity to the idea that the ability to casually drop UDP packets is a *feature*, as it helps avoid problems like Bufferbloat ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat )

Comment: Yes - this is the intention I hoped to convey here. But thank you for being the first person I have ever seen to acknowledge the possibility that packet loss may "never actually happen". That sounds like a statement of potential high reliability... which stands in stark contrast to much of what is written about UDP.

Comment: Painful experience trains programmers not to rely on anything that the specification does not guarantee.  In this case, it's even worse; the specification explicitly *un-guarantees* it, hence the U in UDP :)

Comment: Oh come on - the U in UDP stands for "user". All UDP does is leave out some things that may be _unnecessary_. To equate _unnecessary_ with _unreliable_ is, IMHO, extraordinarily unhelpful. Sure - if all your comms programming is done in the context of the internet/cloud, then UDP on its own is going to be part of an _unreliable system_. But UDP itself is very predictable, well-specified, and in many cases (e.g. the GigE Vision Standard) the basis of a highly reliable system.

Comment: @omatai Networks are *designed* to be unreliable. Reliability is built *on top of* them. The primary feature of UDP, as compared to TCP, is that it does not provide reliability; the application above it is then required to take up that slack.

Comment: @Sneffel I hear you... but that's like saying cars are _designed_ to be unreliable. I would say both cars and networks are designed to be as reliable as possible, but as designed, both are unreliable to a degree. The primary feature of UDP is that it does not provide _reliability of transport_ - nothing more; nothing less. So you are entirely right that the application (or network topology, or combinations of that and other design elements) have to take up the slack. But apologies to all - I've just edited my question to acknowledge the confusion around what "unreliability" means.