# Is UDP collision from Broadcasting nodes possible?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, collision

I am trying to run a simulation to test packet loss in an environment where packet collision is happening. My current setup includes several discrete machines each with their own network interface to send/receive packets. These machines are connected by wifi through an AP. I'm currently using UDP for its ability to **broadcast** packets on a single address. All machines are listening on a shared IP address, something like `192.168.1.255`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26897226/6558745) mentions that UDP packets are unreliable, but will they fail *because* of a collision? Here, I use collision to refer to interference caused by multiple simultaneous transmission. That is, will the simultaneous broadcast of two UDP nodes in the network induce the unreliability I am looking to test? If it's not, will I have to look into changing my network configuration or even start tinkering with kernel code?

If the question is vague, I will say that my end goal involves writing some distributed algorithm that may or may not be resistant to collisions.

Comment: "*I'm currently using UDP for its ability to broadcast packets on a single address*" - multicast accomplishes the same thing, is more efficient than UDP broadcasting, and is a requirement anyway if you ever need to broadcast over IPv6 (which doesn't support UDP broadcasting).

Comment: ***Any*** two packets on the same network can collide, whatever their origin.

Comment: @EJP Not quite. It depends on the *link layer* you're using. For full duplex wired Ethernet for instance, one computer's sending cannot interfere with the same computer's receiving channel. See Jeremey's answer.

Comment: @nabulator Of course, but my point is that broadcast has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to run a simulation to test packet loss in an environment
>   where packet collision is happening.

You might want to include in your question what you mean by the word *collision*.  I'm going to assume in my answer that you mean it in the traditional sense (i.e. two network endpoints transmitting at approximately the same time and thereby "talking over each other" and garbling each other's transmissions such that neither transmission is successful), and not in any broader sense of "a packet got dropped due to network congestion".

> This answer mentions that UDP packets are unreliable, but will they
>   fail because of a collision?

The answer is going to depend entirely on what sort of network hardware you are running your UDP packets over.  The UDP protocol itself is hardware-independent, so it's not going to specify anything about whether collisions can occur or not, since there's no way for it to know.

That said, most low-level networking hardware these days has provisions for avoiding collisions (in the sense I mentioned above) -- for example, modern Ethernet switches do a limited amount of active queueing/buffering of packets when necessary (which is much more efficient and reliable than the old 10Mb/sec Ethernet hubs, which basically just electrically connected the Ethernet RX and TX leads of all the endpoints into one big "shared wire", and hoped for the best)

The other commonly used networking-hardware type, Wi-Fi, also has [mechanisms](https://www.networkcomputing.com/networking/wireless-beginners-part-2-avoiding-collisions/1068414940) to reduce collisions, but that doesn't mean that UDP broadcast over Wi-Fi is a good idea, because it suffers from other issues -- for one thing, the Wi-Fi router has to receive your broadcast packet and rebroadcast it to make sure all other clients can receive it, and worse, it will typically be set to retransmit it at a very slow "legacy" rate, in order to make sure that any ancient Wi-Fi cards out there can still receive the broadcast data.  My advice is that if you're going to be using Wi-Fi, keep your broadcast (and multicast) transmissions to an absolute minimum; even sending separate/identical unicast packets to every other client is usually more efficient(!) -- not to avoid collisions, but rather because even a modest amount of broadcast/multicast traffic can bring your Wi-Fi network to a crawl.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is said to be unreliable because it does not guarantee packet delivery, retransmission, flow control, or congestion. So, the sending/receiving of UDP packets can fail for many reasons: collision, unreliable physical medium, interference, dropping of packets due to router queue overflow, etc.